# How are search results ordered, especially when the search terms are 'question agnostic'?

Tags: discussion, search

I frequently prefer to look for questions on superuser [no one has tried to answer](https://superuser.com/search?q=answers%3A0).

I have never been able to determine how these search results are ordered.  Typically, search results are returned in order of relevance and the search help says they are "weighted heavily towards question title matches", but in this case, you would think that the search would order them based on whatever tab is currently selected (newest, hot, active)?

I ordinarily never stray outside of 'newest', but it's clear the results are not sorted by age.

Comment: Hmm.. I used to be puzzled by the search result sort order as well. but the last time i checked, 'newest' tab seem to make sense to me. Any specific keyword search gave u the problem?

Comment: yes, using `answers:0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not ordered - at least not in a way humans would expect ;). If you search for *relevance* and do not provide any search text which with a relevance ordering can be computed, then I guess the results are listed in that order the SQL query returns them from the database - first found, first out. It depends how the content is stored in the database tables. So it looks arbitrary but it is no random order. <sub>random is messing things up anyway</sub>

Comment: Someone has to.

Comment: But why is it always you?

Comment: Query return order seems rather unsatisfying, but, sadly it's probably true & since you appear to be the only taker on this one, you win!